# Where is http://169.254.169.254/ hosted?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

http://169.254.169.254/ url returns ec2 instance metadata. Where is this url hosted and how is it able to get meta-data of an instance? Is it private ip address which can be accessed only when logged into an ec2 instance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calls to `http://169.254.169.254` are intercepted by the Amazon EC2 hypervisor and are returned to the instance. Such requests do not flow over the network.

Common uses are:

- Instance metadata: `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/`
- User data: `http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data/`

There is also the lesser-known:

- Dynamic Data: `http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/`

For more details, see: [Instance Metadata and User Data - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html)

Comment: Thanks @John. Why was that ipaddress chosen

Comment: No idea, but it might be because it is the last address of the [APIPA - Automatic Private IP Addressing](https://www.lifewire.com/automatic-private-internet-protocol-addressing-816437) range.

Comment: Thanks @JohnRotenstein